# issue with extension point menus in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I created an extension point for action

```
 <menu 
            label="Folding" 
            path="add" 
            id="Plugin.Ruler.EditorMenu">  
            <separator 
                 name="group">  
             </separator>  
        </menu>

 <action 
            id="FoldingAction.Enable" 
            label="FoldingAction" 
            class="EnableClass"
            menubarPath="Plugin.Ruler.EditorMenu/group"
            style="toggle">
        </action>
```

When I press right click then I got the menu.

The problem that in the first time the menu is [] and only in the second time it is working
It cause to issue in the property handling.

The code :

```
                  protected IMenuListener createContextMenuListener() {
    return new IMenuListener() {
        public void menuAboutToShow(IMenuManager menu) {
            String id= menu.getId();
            if (getRulerContextMenuId().equals(id)) {
                setFocus();
                rulerContextMenuAboutToShow(menu);
            } else if (getEditorContextMenuId().equals(id)) {
                setFocus();
                editorContextMenuAboutToShow(menu);
            }
        }
    };
}

           protected final void rulerContextMenuAboutToShow(final IMenuManager menu) {
              super.rulerContextMenuAboutToShow(menu);
              MenuItem[] menus = ((MenuManager) menu).getMenu().getItems();
           }
```

The menu Item are empty on the first click but is it working for the second click.

Comment: Does the other menu works as expected?

Comment: It is working well only in the second time , Is it possible to call to the menu in the other step and init the value and not by the event ?